# Audio via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, audio, avr

Can i use a Bluetooth USB AVR and send audio over Bluetooth to multiple receivers?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?t=17472) might be helpful:

"USB AVR chips can operate in host mode, so in theory it would be possible. In practice, it might take a LOT of work to write the AVR drivers for the dongle, unless the protocol has been published or someone else has already figured out how to do it with that particular dongle."